# How do I serve both HTML and JSON content with Flask?

Tags: python, json, templates, flask, api-design

I'd like to setup a Flask app that has both a GUI and API component.  So here's a simple example that retrieves a list of groups:

```
def get_groups():
    groups = db.session.query(SgmGroup.group_name).order_by(SgmGroup.group_name).all()
    return [group.group_name for group in groups]

@app.route('/list')
def group_list():
    groups_list = get_groups()
    return render_template('groups.html', groups=groups_list)
```

So far so good - this will give the user an HTML list of users, maybe in a table or some other nice GUI format.

But I'd also like to serve JSON content for API requests:

```
@app.route('/api/list')
def api_group_list():
    groups_list = get_groups()
    return jsonify({'groups': group_list})
```

This works - but is this a good idea?  I have two questions:

1) Is this the appropriate way to use Flask when I have two different types of content?  Make an `/endpoint` URL for web browsers (HTML), and an identical `/api/endpoint` URL to handle API requests (JSON)?

2) Or should I combine these two endpoints into a single function?  That would seem to be neater, but how can you determine which endpoint the user accessed?   That is, can the pseudocode below be done?

```
@app.route('/list')
@app.route('/api/list')
def group_list():
    groups_list = get_groups()

    if <user arrived here via the /list endpoint>:
        return render_template('groups.html', groups=groups_list)

    elif <user arrived here via the /api/list endpoint>:
        return jsonify({'groups': group_list})
```

Comment: can also use query param like `?format=json` then test for that and return JSON if it is present or template if not. Personally, I keep seperate blueprints for api routes and html routes.

Comment: I haven't looked into blueprints before (I figured they were an advanced Flask thing beyond my intro-level skills), but thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your second question:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/json')
def index():
    if request.path == '/json':
        return {}
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The doc reference is [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.path).

Comment: Great!  Just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could also split the requests by method to different functions, like so:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return {}
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
```

For project structuring reasons though I would suggest to split up routes to api's and templates in different files.

```
project
├── app
|    ├── views.py
|    └── api.py
└──.....
```